# Including and Calling a Custom JS Script in Angular 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, angular9

I want to use a custom floating button in my angular 9 project. I have added the custom scripts.js file in angular.json file, below is how the structure looks.

```
"scripts": [
               "src/assets/js/custom/action-panel.js",
               "src/assets/js/custom/scripts.js",
           ]
```

below is the code in `scripts.js` file

```
$(document).ready(function() 
  {
      $('.st-actionContainer').launchBtn( { openDuration: 500, closeDuration: 300 } );
  });
```

below is the code i'm using in the html file

```
<div class="st-actionContainer right-bottom">
<div class="st-panel">
    <div class="st-panel-header"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i> Menu</div>
    <div class="st-panel-contents">
        Put menu or icon links here!<br /><br />
        Or make a grid:
    </div>
    <div class="grid">
            <a href="#" class="gridChild"><i class="fa fa-cubes" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="gridChild"><i class="fa fa-database" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="gridChild"><i class="fa fa-send" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="gridChild"><i class="fa fa-tag" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="gridChild"><i class="fa fa-trophy" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="gridChild"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="gridChild"><i class="fa fa-file" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="gridChild"><i class="fa fa-table" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="gridChild"><i class="fa fa-eject" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
        </div>
</div>
<div class="st-btn-container right-bottom">
    <div class="st-button-main"><i class="fa fa-bars" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
</div>
```

Reference of the script file: https://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Material-style-Floating-Button-Panel-Plugin-For-jQuery-st-action-panel.html

I'm following the above practise. My floating button doesn't respond on click, out of nowhere sometimes the floating button work but rest of the time it doesn't. Could anybody let me know where am i going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a racing condition. Test it like this:

```html
$(document).ready(function() 
  {
      alert($('.st-actionContainer')); // to check during debugging wether that button is already in the DOM
      $('.st-actionContainer').launchBtn( { openDuration: 500, closeDuration: 300 } );
  });
```

Make sure

```
 $('.st-actionContainer').launchBtn( { openDuration: 500, closeDuration: 300  );
```

is called after

```
<div class="st-actionContainer right-bottom">
```

has been loaded into the DOM. (e.g. use ngAfterViewInit)

In General jQuery and Angular don´t make for a great combination because of 2 fundamental different ways of approaching a web application.

Comment: Just got to know one more thing, if i open a new tab and modify the code, the tab reloads, without having a focus on it, but then only one time the alert appears, if i click on it the button works, but if all this thing is done with the focus window, it doesn't work.

Comment: On click it does not display anything but when the page is reloaded it shows [object] [object] and displays it 3 to 4 times

Comment: I suggest calling $('.st-actionContainer').launchBtn( { openDuration: 500, closeDuration: 300  ); in ngAfterViewInit() of yourComponent.ts

Comment: i did this `ngOnInit(){
     $('.st-actionContainer').launchBtn( { openDuration: 500, closeDuration: 300  );
  }`

but while compiling throws an error

`Property 'launchBtn' does not exist on type 'JQuery<HTMLElement>'.`